# Wait for seconds isn't working and I don't know why

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

(Sorry if the code is bad I am a beginner)

My problem is that when the zombie hits it doesn't wait to run again. I think that this is because the box collider is getting triggered every second so the HitDelay coroutine gets triggered multiple times. How do I fix this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Health : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        //If health is < 0 then die
        if (healthPoints <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    public float HealthPoints
    {
        get { return healthPoints; }
        set
        {
            healthPoints = value;

        }
    }

    [SerializeField]
    private float healthPoints = 100f;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.name == "Zombie")
        {
            StartCoroutine(HitDelay());         
        }
    }

    IEnumerator HitDelay()
    {
        healthPoints = healthPoints - 25;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by "wait to run again" but HitDelay will get called only when you enter the trigger.  So you need to leave the collider and go back in to trigger it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the attack to go through and not attack until the previous attack is finished, try this.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Health : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Coroutine onHit = null;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.name == "Zombie")
        {
            if(onHit == null)
                onHit = StartCoroutine(HitDelay());         
        }
    }

    IEnumerator HitDelay()
    {
        healthPoints = healthPoints - 25;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
        onHit = null;
    }

}
```

I am storing the HitDelay process so when it tries to trigger again, it will need to be terminated in order to occur again.

Comment: @Jeff Anytime! If this answered your question considering clicking the checkmark next to the answer so anyone else who finds your questions knows that this snippet solved the issue.